# Create directories if not exists based on dot string package name

Tags: java, java-8

I have got a package name, its value is `com.foo.bar.my.app`. I want to create the directories under `src/main/test` if any of the directory in the dot-based string package name does not exists.

I know I can achieve this by split each of the directory name:

```
String pkgName = "com.foo.bar.my.app";
String[] dirs = pkgName.split(".");
```

Then create `File` object for each directory name and use [File#exists()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#exists-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.LinkOption...-) api to check and create new file if not exists.

But is there a more concise elegant way to achieve it in Java 8 ?

Comment: There are multiple ways, I would not say one is more elegant than the other. It all depends on your use case (NIO or File IO). And personal preferences.

Comment: I would like to hear both, doesn't matter nio or io.

Answer (score 7):

It seems you're looking for [`Files.html#createDirectories`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#createDirectories-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute...-), for example:

```
Files.createDirectories(Paths.get(pkgName.replaceAll("\\.", "/")));
```

From the Javadoc:

> Creates a directory by creating all nonexistent parent directories first. Unlike the createDirectory method, an exception is not thrown if the directory could not be created because it already exists.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [File.mkdirs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdirs--) to create any non existing nested directories

```
File file = new File(pkgName.replaceAll("\\.", "/"));

System.out.println(file.mkdirs());
```

> Creates the directory named by this abstract pathname, including any necessary but nonexistent parent directories. Note that if this operation fails it may have succeeded in creating some of the necessary parent directories.

**Returns:**

> true if and only if the directory was created, along with all necessary parent directories; false otherwise

Answer (score 0):

I think that the File.exist() method is java is the best way to check if a certain file is already existant on your computer.

Comment: Yep, but that's not my question. My question is besides the way I know, is there any other elegant options.

Comment: Arguably it is not the best way. Java has a much better file IO library since Java 7. Use the `Files` class instead, not `File` anymore.